# Универсальный конструктор с параметрами

Tags: c#

```
public class A
{
    public A(Control control)
    { 
        //...
    }
}
public class B : A
{
    public B(Control control)
        :base(control)
    {
        //...
    }
}
public class C : A
{
    public C(Control control)
        :base(control)
    {
        //...
    }
}
public static class Factory
{
    public static T Instantiate<T>(Control control)
        where T : A, new()
    {
        return new T(control); // Тут ошибка
    }
}
```

**'T' cannot provide arguments when creating an instance of a variable type**

Через Ativator, говорят, в 11 раз медленнее, чем через new T()
Есть ли какая-то возможность все же передать параметр в универсальный конструктор?

Comment: Ну и что, что в 11 раз медленнее? Для вас в реальности важно, это будет 50 или 500 наносекунд?

Comment: нет, через обобщенный тип упростить не получится, т.к. обобщения поддерживают только конструкторы без параметров.

Comment: @VladD, вообще говоря я просто интересовался, есть ли способ быстрее, ведь если он есть - зачем тратить 55 наносекунд, если можно потратить 5. В любом случае, пока что нельзя передавать параметры, так что буду искать другое решение.

Comment: @Bloodskys: Ну, хм. Если ваш код работает с графикой, то там потери в 500 наносекунд — это как сгоревшая спичка по сравнению с запуском в космос ракеты.

Comment: Можно проверять тип `T` и вызывать конкретный конструктор. Не уверен, будет ли это ускорением. А что, реально у вас профайлер показал проблему с временем в этой точке? Или это у вас [преждевременная оптимизация](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2009/12/blog-post_08.html)?

Comment: @VladD, повторю еще раз: я ничего не оптимизировал еще, я лишь узнал, нет ли очевидного другого способа решения :) А касаемо конкретного конструктора - это, к сожалению, неприемлимый вариант.

Comment: Очевидный и естественный вариант — `Activator.CreateInstance`. По вашим словам, вы не хотите его использовать, т. к. он «говорят, в 11 раз медленнее». Это значит, что вы пытаетесь соптимизировать. По крайней мере, мне так показалось из ваших слов.

Comment: @VladD, да, вам действительно показалось. Я говорю что "вычитал, что микроскопом забивать гвозди - несуразно", а вы вместо того, чтобы предложить молоток (или указать на его отсутствие) говорите что я пытаюсь оптимизировать, что является пустым, ведь и микроскопом нормально забивается.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50656/discussion-between-bloodskys-and-vladd).

Comment: `Activator.CreateInstance` не может быть 11 раз медленнее, чем `new T()` очень простой причине - `new T()` в генериках компилируется в вызов `Activator.CreateInstance`. :)

Comment: @PashaPash, Если вам интересно - можете найти топик, где есть выкладки с цифрами вроде "Activator - 12000, new() - 1100".

Comment: @Bloodskys не нашел. поделитесь ссылкой. вы уверены что там сравнивали Activator c new T() в генерике (как у вас в вопросе?). а не Activator с просто new()?

Comment: @Bloodskys судя по всему вы про вот этот топик - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6069959/. Там сравнивается вызов Activator (медленный) с вызовом `new TestClass()` (с указанием конретного типа). вызов new TestClass компилируется в быстрый вызов newobj. Но вот вызов вызов new T(), где T - generic parameter c new() - компилируется не в newobj, а в такой же медленный вызов Activator.CreateInstance - вот вам топик с измерениями http://stackoverflow.com/a/16162809/1988244.

Comment: @Bloodskys это особенность реализации генериков и их поддержки в рантайме - JIT компилирует отдельные реализации для каждого value type и одну общую реализацию для всех reference type. Поэтому он просто физически не может вписать вызов разных конструкторов для разных типов - и вписывает вызов активатора.

Comment: @PashaPash, вот оно что. Спасибо за разъяснение, теперь все встало на свои места!

Answer (score 4):

```
public static class Factory
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<Control, A>> _typeToActivator = new Dictionary<Type, Func<Control, A>>
    {
        [typeof(A)] = (c) => new A(c),
        [typeof(B)] = (c) => new B(c),
        [typeof(C)] = (c) => new C(c),
    };

    public static T Instantiate<T>(Control control)
        where T : A
    {
        return (T)_typeToActivator[typeof(T)](control);
    }
}
```

Если не хотите заполнять словарь _typeToActivator в ручную, можете используя следующий метод:

```
private static Func<Control, T> CreateActivator<T>() where T:A
{
    var ctor = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] {typeof(Control)});
    var prm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Control));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<Control, T>>(
        Expression.New(ctor, prm), prm
    ).Compile();
}
```

т.е. можете найти все классы, производные от A, и имеющие нужный конструктор используя Reflection, и заполнить словарь.